# how to plot multiple ggscatter plots from a for loop on same page

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, ggpubr

I have several samples for which I generated a plot. As I have many samples, I used a for loop. So I have now multiple single plot and I would like to show them in one page. I am having trouble since plot_ is overwritten in the loop.
below is my loop generating the plots:

```
plot_ =  for (i in unique(df$samples_ID)) {
df_subset = df[which(df$samples_ID == i),]
print(ggscatter(data = df_subset, x = 'meanT', y= 'meanCF',
add = "reg.line", conf.int =TRUE, cor.coef =TRUE,
cor.coeff.args=list(label.x.npc = 0.3, label.y.npc = 0.001), 
cor.method ="pearson", 
xlab="mean_Tumor", ylab="mean_CF",
title = i))
}
```

I have already tried to add:

```
par(mfrow = c(8,3))
```

but it looks that this function does not work with ggscatter.

Would you have a simple way to manage this ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to use `grid.arrange` from [gridExtra](https://cran.r-project.org/package=gridExtra) package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html

Comment: For combining grid/ggplot2-based plots also see packages **cowplot**, **egg**, and **patchwork** (this last one is currently only on GitHub).